# Gravity Form - get field values and sum only if field value is 1

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have 4 number fields on gravity form
User can input values between 1 to 5
I want to count how many values are 1 and sum up total.

So for e.g.

```
Field 1 = 1
Field 2 = 4
Field 3 = 5
Field 4 = 1
```

Then total no. of 1 are 2 (Field 1 + Field 4)

How can i make this work to gravity form?

Comment: When you say sum up the total? Do you mean the total number of 1-value fields?

Comment: yes exactly, count the specific value defined. In the example above i just want to sum up value that matches 1 and ignore all value. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working form export your can import and play around with.

[Download Form Export](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/689144/files/gravityforms-export-2016-10-22.json)

The pertinent code (inside the HTML block):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    var $inputs = $( '#input_1484_1, #input_1484_2, #input_1484_3' ),
        $sumInput = $( '#input_1484_4' );

    $inputs.change( function() {

        var oneSum = 0;

        $inputs.each( function() {
            if( parseInt( $( this ).val() ) === 1 ) {
                oneSum += parseInt( $( this ).val() );
            }
        } );

        $sumInput.val( oneSum );

    } );

} );
</script>
```

To implement this on your own form, you will need to:

- Update the `$inputs` variable with the input HTML IDs for each Number field you wish to include in the calculation.
- Update the `$sumInput` variable with the input HTML ID of the Number field in which you would like to sum the number of 1-value fields.

Comment: Thanks so much,  It worked perfect. Is it also possible to count value of radio fields e.g. If i have many radio fields with value Yes no, then i want to sum up how many Yes are there.

Comment: I have figured it out as i have used input fields to count specific text values as well. Here is the code

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) { 
    var $inputs = $( '#input_6_1, #input_6_2, #input_6_3' ),
        $sumInput = $( '#input_6_4' );
$inputs.change( function() {
    var oneSum = 0; 
    $inputs.each( function() {
       if( $( this ).val() == "Y" || $( this ).val() == "y" ) {
            oneSum += 1;
        }
    } );
    $sumInput.val( oneSum );
} );
} );
</script>